# Mono sound output in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, mono

Is there an easy way of forcing mono sound output - for one ear, one earphone, one speaker?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[~VIA~ Translated from French](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1096171) (and considering the correction signaled at the end of the forum page)

You can use the module to remap pulseaudio:

In a terminal:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

It will send you the name of the stereo output used.
Then you type (replacing with the **name** you have found):

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=THE_NAME_FROM_THE_PREVIOUS_COMMAND channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

(In my case that was:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1e.2.analog-stereo channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

)

If you open the Sound Preferences you should now have a mono output available.
To have that permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

then you add in the file:

```
#Remapping output stereo to mono
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=THE_NAME_FROM_THE_PREVIOUS_COMMAND channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

[image]

(The image is from the sound settings of Elementary OS Luna).

Comment: Very Useful... ;-)

Comment: How do you change the name of the new sink, to change the default name 'Remapped Built-in Audio Analog Stereo' in the System Settings - Sound GUI?

Comment: Warning to people using PulseAudio Multiband Equalizer: this fix successfully put my sound output to mono but the equalizer stopped working.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I'd suggest getting rid of gksudo since it's been removed from Ubuntu though.

Comment: @jII Use `sink_properties="device.description='your preferred description'"` in the command line.

Comment: @jarno Would you be so kind as to add that to this answer?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica--notmaynard I made another answer

Comment: Didn't the question ask output to one channel only?

Answer (score 12):

Yet another solution.
I like command line solution and used it very long time.

But I found good application: [PulseEffects](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects) and there is a way to make mono with good GUI app.

#### Installation:

`flatpak install com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects`
if u don't have `flatpak` yet (on ubuntu for example), you can [install it](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/)

#### Configuration

1. Stereo Tools
2. Stereo Mix
3. LR > L+R  (Mono Sum L+R)

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. My sound card doesn't support mono despite dozens of variants of HD this and surround sound that... has no one else used broken headphones? The other features look great too.

Comment: It does support mono. Mono is just same signal on both channels.
You can always make mono sound physically: just solder left and right channel (on Jack plug) together and you will get mono output.

Comment: Thanks for the definition. After trying with Pulse Audio and Gnome Alsa Mixer and looking through all the output options, I never found any option to output mono audio. And no, physically tampering with the hardware does not mean you're producing a mono signal. (Nor is it "support" any more than replacing the hardware is.) Consider BT headphones, Chromecast/HDMI, remote streaming, etc. This came up recently where a (single) YT video was missing one channel (the capture messed up.) Software solutions always, always come before you mess with solder.

Comment: Agree. I mean, that mono si easy deal: just mathematically add 2 signals (left right) and you get mono

Answer (score 6):

This answer is a mix of the two answers, witch are not generic (channels names "left" and "right" are defined by the soundcard vendor and can vary).

The global idea is to use [module-remap-sink](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index12h3) as suggested by other answers.
We will replace **[skinID], [left_channel_name] and [right_channel_name]** by values found later:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=combined-mono master=[skinID] channels=4 master_channel_map=[right_channel_name],[left_channel_name],[right_channel_name],[left_channel_name] channel_map=[left_channel_name],[left_channel_name],[right_channel_name],[right_channel_name]
```

This will create a **double-mono** sink output that we can set to be the default one (done below).

### 1 - find [skinID]

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

In my case, only one sink is present; corresponding to the only sound card available:

```
index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
```

=> I can use either "0" or "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo" for [skinID]

### 2 - find [left_channel_name] and [right_channel_name]

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep -m1 "channel map:"
```

In my case, it gives:

```
channel map: front-left,front-right
```

So, for me [left_channel_name] = "front-left" and [right_channel_name]="front-right"

### 3 - Apply changes

To make changes effective, I'll to run (in my case)

```
pactl load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=combined-mono master=0 channels=4 master_channel_map=front-right,front-left,front-right,front-left channel_map=front-left,front-left,front-right,front-right
pactl set-default-sink combined-mono
```

=> the first command's arguments are to adapt to each case ! Read the entiere post for details

To verify, you can play [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8ODm-F9-IM)

### 4 (optional) - Make changes permanant

To keep this settings and have them applied each time the computer starts:

- copy `/etc/pulse/default.pa` => ~/.pulse/default.pa (if not already done)
- add the two commands to the end of file, **without "pactl " at the beginning**

  => in my case, this gives:

  ```
  load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=combined-mono master=0 channels=4 master_channel_map=front-right,front-left,front-right,front-left channel_map=front-left,front-left,front-right,front-right
  set-default-sink combined-mono
  ```

Comment: skinID => sinkID

Answer (score 4):

Installing Gnome Alsa Mixer by executing

```
$sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer
```

there are some options:

"Mono Output Select" and "Mix Mono"

[image]

Comment: These options do not appear on every soundcard; when I installed it the only options there were "auto-mute", "IEC958" and "Loopback mixing", nothing to do with mono outputs.

Answer (score 4):

I had problems with both of these answers.  When I tried the accepted answer, the only thing that would come out of the speaker was noise.  After some searching, I found another solution that might work better for you:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo channels=4 channel_map=left,right,left,right master_channel_map=left,left,right,right
```

Replace alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo with the sink name you get from

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

Follow the steps in the accepted answer if you would like to make this solution permanent.

Comment: I get the same sink name as you, but when I run the command I get the output: >>> Module load failed. Using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

The following sets mono audio to the left channel of sink 0 so it forces sound on one speaker only:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink master=0 sink_name=mono-to-left sink_properties='device.description="mono to left of sink 0"' channels=1 channel_map=mono master_channel_map=left
```

If you want mono sound on all channels, apply the following:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink master=0 sink_name=mono sink_properties='device.description="mono to sink 0"' channels=1 channel_map=mono
```

I have not tested that with output sinks that have more than two channels.