# How to direct sound to one headphone ubuntu vlc?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, vlc-media-player, surround-sound

My right earpiece is gone. So , I would like to send the sound only to left headphone . Is it possible ??the thing is , some sound is low in one earpiece and high in other , like the base is very low in left but louder in right. But Now I have to make all equal.

Comment: With one earpiece gone, you will only get sound from the remaining one. Am I wrong? Are you asking how to send the signal for the right earpiece to the left one? Please clarify.

Comment: You can use the mixer to mute one of the channels. However if your source is in stereo this might sound weird. In which you might want to check this similar post: 
http://superuser.com/questions/657876/mono-sound-output-in-ubuntu

Comment: I edited the question , Charlie , and @Hennes, when I run the command I get the output: >>> Module load failed. Using Ubuntu 14.04