# Direct left channel to right one due to left headphone not working

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, audio-streaming

My left headphone is no longer working. Is there an easy way to direct the left channel to the right one so that both channels stream through only the right headphone? Muting the left side doesn't solve my problem (as it only mutes the sound, it doesn't redirect it or anything).

My question is essentially [this](https://superuser.com/questions/840063/how-to-direct-sound-to-one-headphone-ubuntu-vlc) but for Windows 7.

My question is, however,  [not this](https://superuser.com/questions/351249/how-do-i-force-single-only-channel-audio-in-youtube-flash-videos-to-play-in-bo) as I have the opposite problem (2 channels through 1 speaker, rather than 1 channel through two speakers).

Comment: Can you find any "mono" options in your advanced sound controls in Control panel? Also check for something called "Headphone virtualization".

Comment: I do have headphone virtualization which I enabled, but nothing aking to 'mono', does that mean it's not possible?

Comment: You could be able to get a "mono" option from another driver (a newer driver for your soundcard, or a basic Windows driver instead of the driver from your soundcard), or installing some other audio software that comes with your card (like a "mixer").

Comment: I see, is this what would essentially allow me to have what I want? Could I not achieve this through some software? Like recording programs that allow a user to record audio even if the sound card doesn't support it. I'll have a look for a newer driver though, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yes, the rationale is that if you can get mono sound, the 2 channels get mixed in just one. Then you can shift the balance 100% to the right. See http://superuser.com/questions/117494/force-windows-to-output-only-mono-sound

Comment: I've just updated the driver and sadly said option hasn't surfaced in the Properties menu. Oh, well. I do appreciate your advice though!

Comment: There are more options you can try in that answer I linked above.